# Docker Upgrade from v1.11 to v1.12 using apt-get on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, upgrade

I was trying to upgrade docker as is suggsted in [its manual](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#upgrade-docker)

```
    sudo apt-get upgrade docker-engine
```

For some unknown reasons this will result in fetching and unpacking almost every package and library in my linux ( linux-images, lightdm, jvm,etc.). This has been going on for an hour now.

Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong and how it can be stopped without messing up my Ubuntu installation?
( in case you are planning to upgrade your docker using this, just don't. a purge an reinstall is a much better choice if you like your Ubuntu)

Comment: Note that, at time of writing, you can't upgrade to 1.12 via APT anyway, because it's still in the release candidate stage.

Comment: @jwodder , true :(

Comment: `sudo apt-get  install --only-upgrade docker-engine` should do

Comment: @jwodder Then how could I upgrade to 1.12?

Comment: @paty.r15: Technically, 1.12 doesn't exist yet, so either wait a few days or get a time machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apt-get upgrade` always upgrades all the packages on your machine.

You want

```
$ apt-get update && apt-get install docker-engine -y
```

Comment: That instruction is not working for me because v1.12 is experimental, in pre-release. Any ideas of how to install it?

Comment: The deb command is `curl -fsSL https://test.docker.com/ | sh`, see https://github.com/docker/docker/releases in the `Downloads` section